# Replacing preg_replace e modifier

Tags: php, deprecated

I am re doing an old project at work and getting a ton of these:

```
Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead
```

Looking at line 74:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\&\#([0-9]+)\;/me', "code2utf('\\1',{$lo})",$str);
```

How can I convert that to use the new call back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily.

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/&#(\d+);/', function($m) use ($lo) {
    return code2utf($m[1],$lo);
}, $str);
```

The important thing here is the `use ($lo)`, as it allows you to "import" the `$lo` variable into your callback.

I've also cleaned up your regex - way too many backslashes ;)

Comment: Okay cool, get it now i have seen a working example. Thanks.